# How can I apply a filter using a calculated control field against blended data?

Tags: looker-studio

When I create a filter using a calculated control field against blended data, the filter does not work.

- Sample report: https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/a7b8b913-466d-4afe-8c57-20821a1f0aec
- Sample source data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QHU_pZYCpDg5nAyIRrnFZB-en6icOaLxZ1fdG3GntEI/edit#gid=1536448669

I have added `table1` and `table2` from my source to the report. I created a blended table by combining them on `ID`.

I add a table chart to the report using the blended table as the source.

- I **can** filter using the blended table's ID field
- I **can** filter using the blended table's name field
- I **can** filter using the `table1` data source and creating a calculated control field using: `CONCAT(name, " (", ID ,")")`

But, I **cannot** filter using the blended table and creating a calculated control field using: `CONCAT(name, " (", ID ,")")`

This looks like a bug to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, was able to replicate the issue (chart-level [calculated field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) in a [blend](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061420) not working as expected). For future reference on the status of the issue, a bug report titled [Bug with creating calculated control fields in filters against a blended data](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240662893) was created on 30 Jul 2022 with the details in the question.

In this case:

- ***Join operator***: Left Outer
- ***Required fields***: In the 1st (left) table

Therefore one workaround is to create the [calculated field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) in the [blended](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061420) data source (implemented in the [10 Jun 2021 update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10331528#june-10-2021)), which filters values as expected:

```
CONCAT(name, " (", ID, ")")
```

[image: blend_formula_dimension_3]

The complete process:

### 1) Blend Fields

| **Data Source**: | table1 | table2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Dimension 1**: | `ID` | `report ID` |
| **Dimension 2**: | `name` | `ID` |
| **Dimension 3**: **Formula**: | `name (ID)` `CONCAT(name, " (", ID ,")")` | `score` |
| **Image**: | [image: table_1] | [image: table_2] |

### 2) Join Configuration

| Join Description | Table 1 Table 2 |
| --- | --- |
| **Join Operator**: | Left Outer |
| **Join Condition 1**: | `ID (table1)` `ID (table2)` |
| **Image**: | [image: join_config] |

The blend will create 5 fields:

| Fields |
| --- |
| `name` |
| `name (ID)` |
| `ID` |
| `report ID` |
| `score` |

### 3) Control

| Description | Details |
| --- | --- |
| **Type**: | [Drop-down list](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/11335992) |
| **Control field**: | `name (ID)` |

Publicly editable [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/4dbff140-2bd1-49ae-93c3-f5289c2a4f1a) report (embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xVVfGKHu2cBgnwE7PfZNIuqnFCZBY971Kg5hLJZTobs/edit?usp=sharing) data source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: gif]

Comment: The only issue with this is you can't create calculated fields combining data from two different sources in the blend. You can only do that in the report. :/

Comment: Yes :( it works "*in this [specific] case: **Join operator**: Left Outer **Required fields**: In the 1st (left) table*"...Looking for another workaround though (to "*create calculated fields combining data from two different source*" ); also trying to figure out when the issue seems to start around as I remember that it had worked previously (although can't seem to find reports on it at the moment). Will have a look through older reports & posts and if it worked previously will try & narrow down a time period (as the issue could have arisen from a specific update) & Will update if there's news