# Looker Studio: How to override or choose null values as a default selection for a control

Tags: looker-studio

Sample Report: 
https://datastudio.google.com/u/2/reporting/e908056b-d027-4503-8c8b-2c8a258d9b20/page/5DZAD

Sample Source Data: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IS_FuQc0VkSHXQP46UibZBeVNqBpMfAnVi-JjxkrC9U/edit?usp=sharing

**Setup:**

I am trying to set up a system where variable date ranges can be compared within the same data set. I have done so by blending the data source with itself on a full outer join with an added text join key (“Source 1” and “Source 2”).
The blend results in the following fields:

- Date 1, Date 2, Leads 1, Leads 2

**Original Data Source:**

| Date | Leads |
| --- | --- |
| Q1, 2022 | 4 |
| Q2, 2022 | 8 |
| Q3, 2022 | 13 |
| Q4, 2022 | 17 |

**Data Source blended with itself:**

| Date 1 | Date 2 | Leads 1 | Leads 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | Q1, 2022 | null | 4 |
| null | Q2, 2022 | null | 8 |
| null | Q3, 2022 | null | 13 |
| null | Q4, 2022 | null | 17 |
| Q1, 2022 | null | 4 | null |
| Q2, 2022 | null | 8 | null |
| Q3, 2022 | null | 13 | null |
| Q4, 2022 | null | 17 | null |

I then created drop-down list controls for Date 1 and Date 2. These controls will calculate a % Difference between the date ranges that are set.

The setup is similar to this: https://www.sumified.com/how-to-create-a-custom-date-range-comparison-in-data-studio?fbclid=IwAR2P8h6etil__5Y_hmKmJII7yYl2zPQ8lmm9N6T97amwoa-jbkssCi72BaA

**Problem Statement:**

The problem is that due to the nature of the blend, the ‘null’ data set must be selected for both date ranges at all times in order for the metrics to calculate properly. This is not the most user-friendly setup.

I believe ensuring the ‘null’ data set is selected all times can be accomplished via either one of two methods:

**Method 1:** Renaming the null values something that can be detected by the default selection field of the controls via a COALESCE. For the sake of simplicity, I will define the null values as "Q1, 1900"

- The problem with this method is that a coalesced date dimension cannot be created until after the blend, and therefore will not properly filter. The issue is indicated in this problem: [How can I apply a filter using a calculated control field against blended data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73173051/how-can-i-apply-a-filter-using-a-calculated-control-field-against-blended-data)

**Method 2:** Setting “null” as the default selection field of the controls:

- The issue with this is that when “null” is entered as a default selection, the string literal “null” is interpreted, rather than the actual null data.

**Desired Outcome:**

| Date 1 | Date 2 | Leads 1 | Leads 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Q1, 1900 | Q1, 2022 | null | 4 |
| Q1, 1900 | Q2, 2022 | null | 8 |
| Q1, 1900 | Q3, 2022 | null | 13 |
| Q1, 1900 | Q4, 2022 | null | 17 |
| Q1, 2022 | Q1, 1900 | 4 | null |
| Q2, 2022 | Q1, 1900 | 8 | null |
| Q3, 2022 | Q1, 1900 | 13 | null |
| Q4, 2022 | Q1, 1900 | 17 | null |

I am also open to setting up the system differently if it will bring about the desired outcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding your static Date of Q1 1900 as a metric to one of the blends and joined on that? Below I have an example of a static number, but dates should work as well. You could join the static date to the dynamic date, which because no values will match, should give you the intended result.

[image]